# Fetch output of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in a VB .net application

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am trying to get a simple hello world output in vb from a pl/sql anonymous block

As far as I tried

```
    Imports System.Data
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
           + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=vmDA2D319)(PORT=1521))" _
           + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));" _
           + "User Id=hr;Password=hr;"
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "set server output on;" & vbNewLine & "DECLARE" & vbNewLine & "message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; " & vbNewLine & "BEGIN()" & vbNewLine & "dbms_output.put_line(message);" & vbNewLine & "END;" & vbNewLine & "/"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        Label1.Text = dr.ExecuteReader
        conn.Dispose()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now this is the Part where I am stuck now. I just want fetch the output in a textbox actually.

But I am just trying to get the output in a label or maybe in a messagebox first.

UPDATE

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
           + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=vmDA2D319)(PORT=1521))" _
           + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));" _
           + "User Id=hr;Password=hr;"
    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(oradb)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "set server output on;" & vbNewLine & "DECLARE" & vbNewLine & "return_value VARCHAR2(100) := 'Hello World!';" & vbNewLine & "get_status INTEGER;" & vbNewLine & "BEGIN" & vbNewLine & "DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINE (return_value, get_status);" & vbNewLine & "IF get_status = 0" & vbNewLine & "THEN" & vbNewLine & "RETURN return_value;" & vbNewLine & "ELSE" & vbNewLine & "RETURN NULL;" & vbNewLine & "END IF;" & vbNewLine & "END;" & vbNewLine & "/"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("return_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100)
    cmd.Parameters("return_value").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    Label1.Text = cmd.Parameters("return_value").Value
        conn.Dispose()


End Sub
```

I am getting error at cmd.ExecuteScalar() 
with ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: I wouldn't be using dbms_output for your situation. Why not declare an out parameter instead? Also you don't need parentheses after your BEGIN.

Comment: You can use dmbs_output.get_lines() to put the output of put_line into a char array in your procedure, and then return the char array as an output parameter of your oraclecommand